# Vista para editar un modelo que tiene una lista de otro modelo

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Tengo los siguientes modelos:

```
public class Receta
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }       
    public ICollection<Ingredientes> Ingredientess { get; set; }
}
```

Que a su vez:

```
public class Ingredient
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Cuando creamos una receta, debemos poder seleccionar los ingredientes de los ya existentes, o ***poder crear uno nuevo***

No sé como poder crear la vista que haga eso, y como asociarlo a los modelos.

Saludos, y gracias.

Comment: ¿Que cosa no sabes asociar a los modelos? Estas usando Entity Framework?

Comment: Releyendo, he visto que está un poco mal explicado. Estoy usando MCV core, tengo el modelo creado. Quiero crear una vista que me permita crear el modelo "receta", ademas del nombre, poder añadirle los ingredientes necesarios, ya sea seleccionando de los ya existentes, o crear uno nuevo. No se como crear esa vista. Hasta ahora, asociaba a la vista un modelo, y a través de un formulario rellenaba las propiedades, pero no se como hacerlo con la lista de ingredientes.

Comment: Está algo extenso tu caso. Básicamente necesitas crear una tabla con los ingredientes que ya existen en tu receta, con una columna por cada propiedad. Checa por la opción de foreach (https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/aspnet-mvc/foreach-loop-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-view-engine-example). Una vez que tengas eso, para agregar un nuevo ingrediente te sugiero uses vistas parciales (modal) para agregar por ajax el nuevo ingrediente. Suerte.